# Meaning of Kusto CSL acronym

Tags: azure-data-explorer

This question is pretty straightforward: relating to Microsoft Kusto, what does the acronym CSL stand for? I know what CSL is used for, but there seems to be a distinct lack of information about what those three letters actually represent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CSL = **C**ousteau **S**emantic **L**anguage.

Cousteau was later renamed into Kusto (sounds the same but simpler to write for non-French speakers :)).

However CSL is deprecated, and users are encouraged to use KQL (Kusto Query Language) instead (although both work).

Comment: Thanks for solving this mystery, and the heads up on the deprecation!